# why mixed FMUL and FMLA is slower than pure FMUL or FMLA on Cortex-A53

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, arm, neon

There are 3 code blocks:

A:

```
asm volatile(
    "fmla   v0.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v1.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v2.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v3.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v4.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v5.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v6.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v7.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v8.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v9.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v10.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v11.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v12.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v13.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v14.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v15.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[3]  \r\n"
    :
    :
    : "v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7",
      "v8", "v9", "v10", "v11", "v12", "v13", "v14", "v15");
```

B:

```
asm volatile(
    "fmul   v0.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v1.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v2.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v3.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v4.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v5.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v6.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v7.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v8.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmul   v9.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmul  v10.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmul  v11.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmul  v12.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmul  v13.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmul  v14.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmul  v15.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[3]  \r\n"
    :
    :
    : "v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7",
      "v8", "v9", "v10", "v11", "v12", "v13", "v14", "v15");
```

C:

```
asm volatile(
    "fmla   v0.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v1.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v2.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v3.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v4.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v5.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v6.4s, v30.4s, v22.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v7.4s, v31.4s, v22.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v8.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmla   v9.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[0]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v10.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v11.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[1]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v12.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v13.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[2]  \r\n"
    "fmla  v14.4s, v30.4s, v23.s[3]  \r\n"
    "fmul  v15.4s, v31.4s, v23.s[3]  \r\n"
    :
    :
    : "v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7",
      "v8", "v9", "v10", "v11", "v12", "v13", "v14", "v15");
```

The only difference between A and B is FMLA vs. FMUL, and the only difference

between A and C is the last FMLA instruction is changed to FMUL

And there will be some codes to execute each block many times and record the time cost:

```
auto start=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for(int i=0; i<1000*1000*1000; i++) {
    <Block A or B or C>;
}
auto end=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
printf("%f\n", std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end-start).count());
```

But the result is A and B use almost the same time, while C is much more slower than A and B (cost near 30% more time than A and B).

Test environment:

Raspbery Pi 3 with pi64 (https://github.com/bamarni/pi64 a 64bit Debian OS)

compiler: g++ 7.2.0

By the way, I have tested this on some other ARMv8 CPU:

```
 SoC or Board            CPU Micro-arch           Result
Raspbery Pi 3              Cortex-A53              Slow
  A MTK Soc                Cortex-A53              Slow
Snapdragon 820          Kyro by Qualcomm           Same
  NVIDIA TX2               Cortex-A57              Same
  NVIDIA TX2            Denver2 by NVIDIA          Same
```

It seem's this problem will only appear on Cortex-A53 or on in-order micro-architecture.

I have read the deassembled code and it looks fine.

Comment: Why are you writing asm by hand rather than just writing clear C++ and letting the compilers optimizer worry about choosing the best instructions (it's usually pretty good at that)?

Comment: mixing instructions with different latencies might cause write-back conflicts, but IDK enough about ARM microarchitecture performance details to answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes but Cortex A53 doesn't has a clear document about its microarchitecture's performance for each instruction. Cortex A57 does has a useful document: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.uan0015b/Cortex_A57_Software_Optimization_Guide_external.pdf

Comment: @JesperJuhl yeah maybe I should remove the "c++" tag away

Comment: `fmla` is fused multiply accumulate, and it needs a different kind of bit operations internally than `fmul`, and thus, switching is necessary which costs time. You are running your asm code in a loop, and the out-of-order engine on the `big` cluster will remove most of the instructions from ROB in runtime since the results are abandoned in the end while the in-order `Cortex-A53` can't do this. Maybe you should read and write the input/output from/to a memory buffer for a more realistic test.